# How to write test cases for afterviewInit angular?

Tags: unit-testing, ts-jest, angular-test

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    var link = document.getElementById("mat-chip-list-0");
    link.removeAttribute("aria-multiselectable");
    link.removeAttribute("aria-orientation");
  }
```

How do i write test cases for the above method using jest?
jest version:28
Angular:14